# Maximum subarray algorithm in clojure

Tags: clojure

kanade's algorithm solves the [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). i'm trying to learn clojure, so i came up with this implementation:

```
(defn max-subarray [xs]
  (last
    (reduce
      (fn [[here sofar] x]
        (let [new-here (max 0 (+ here x))]
          [new-here (max new-here sofar)]))
      [0 0]
      xs)))
```

this seems really verbose. **is there a cleaner way to implement this algorithm in clojure**?

Comment: That looks like pretty good clojure to me, It's not obvious that it needs to be "improved". It can be expressed with map and with loop/recur though they are equally good.

Comment: another solution - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray#Clojure

Comment: I agree with @ArthurUlfeldt's comment, this is perfectly fine Clojure. I'd personally use `peek` in place of `last`, `peek` being much more efficient with vectors (O(1) in contrast to `last`'s O(n)) and equally clear to my eye in terms of intent; if you find `last` clearer, though, it's completely fine on a vector of size 2.

Comment: @edbond i confess after staring at that rosettacode impl and spending some time reading through those fn's docs, i have no clue how it works :) tho near as i can tell it actually compares the sum of every subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment on the question, I believe the OP's approach is optimal. That's given the fully general problem in which the input is a seqable of arbitrary numbers.

However, if the requirement were added that the input should be a collection of longs (or doubles; other primitives are fine too, as long as we're not mixing integers with floating-point numbers), a `loop` / `recur` based solution could be made to be significantly faster by taking advantage of primitive arithmetic:

```
(defn max-subarray-prim [xs]
  (loop [xs (seq xs) here 0 so-far 0]
    (if xs
      (let [x (long (first xs))
            new-here (max 0 (+ here x))]
        (recur (next xs) new-here (max new-here so-far)))
      so-far)))
```

This is actually quite readable to my eye, though I do prefer `reduce` where there is no particular reason to use `loop` / `recur`. The hope now is that `loop`'s ability to keep `here` and `so-far` unboxed throughout the loop's execution will make enough of a difference performance-wise.

To benchmark this, I generated a vector of 100000 random integers from the range -50000, ..., 49999:

```
(def xs (vec (repeatedly 100000 #(- (rand-int 100000) 50000))))
```

Sanity check (`max-subarray-orig` refers to the OP's implementation):

```
(= (max-subarray-orig xs) (max-subarray-prim xs))
;= true
```

[Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) benchmarks:

```
(do (c/bench (max-subarray-orig xs))
    (flush)
    (c/bench (max-subarray-prim xs)))
WARNING: Final GC required 3.8238570080506156 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 11460 in 60 samples of 191 calls.
             Execution time mean : 5.295551 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 97.329399 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 5.106146 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 5.456003 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.038603 ns
Evaluation count : 28560 in 60 samples of 476 calls.
             Execution time mean : 2.121256 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 42.014943 µs
   Execution time lower quantile : 2.045558 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 2.206587 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 2.038603 ns

Found 5 outliers in 60 samples (8.3333 %)
    low-severe   1 (1.6667 %)
    low-mild     4 (6.6667 %)
 Variance from outliers : 7.8724 % Variance is slightly inflated by outliers
```

So that's a jump from ~5.29 ms to ~2.12 ms per call.

Comment: It goes without saying that for an actual array of primitives we could do even better.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using loop and recur to more closely mimic the example in the wikipedia page.

```
user> (defn max-subarray [xs]                                           
        (loop [here 0 sofar 0 ar xs]                                    
              (if (not (empty? ar))                                     
                  (let [x (first ar) new-here (max 0 (+ here x))]       
                    (recur new-here (max new-here sofar) (rest ar)))    
                sofar)))                                                
#'user/max-subarray                                                     
user> (max-subarray [0 -1 1 2 -4 3])                                    
3
```

Some people may find this easier to follow, others prefer reduce or map.

Comment: Two notes: `(seq xs)` is preferred to `(not (empty? xs))` (in fact the docstring on `empty?` says so), because `empty?` is implemented as `(not (seq xs))`; also, you can just call `seq` on the input in the beginning (in the bindings vector) and then use `next` in `recur` and simply use `ar` as the condition (since `next` acts like `seq` composed with `rest` -- but possibly more efficiently).